# Import pdf Files to Samsung Galaxy Tab S7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, pdf, import

How do I import pdf files from my computer to my Galaxy Tab S7 5G?

Answer (score 1):

You can just connect them using a USB cable.

Alternatively you can use Bluetooth (if your computer supports it), or upload the PDF files to the cloud (e.g. Google Drive), or send them via email to youself.